# How to fillna based on multiples conditions

Tags: pandas

**Initial dataframe:**

```
data = [[1, 2, "qw"], 
        [2, 1, "er"], 
        [2, 2, "xy"],
        [1, 2, np.nan],
        [2, 2, np.nan]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["c1", "c2", "c3"])
```

[image]

**What I'm looking for:**

[image]

Comment: what are the conditions?

Comment: Check equality c1 and c2 (ex: index0 and index3)

Comment: groupby and ffill `df['c3'] = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])['c3'].ffill()`

Comment: @AdilBlanco Your question needs to be clearer.  But If I were to guess at what you needed, I'd agree with Yo_Chris.

Comment: @Yo_Chris your answer was good, why did you delete it?

Comment: @AdilBlanco I did not submit an answer, just the comment.

Comment: @Yo_Chris sorry I do not know who posted this: `df['c3'] = df.groupby(['c1','c2']).transform(pd.DataFrame.ffill)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas there are more than one way of getting things done. Below is one of the ways. I used your definition of the dataframe above:

```
X = df[~df["c3"].isna()]
df = df.merge(X, how="left", on=["c1", "c2"])
df.drop("c3_x", axis=1, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={"c3_y": "c3"}, inplace=True)
```

Basically merging the df with itself and getting rid of NAs. Cheers